# SCD-Type1 in single flow

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a scenario where type-1 insert and update are done in individual flow with source qualifier override as follows:

sq(override query)-->exp-->tgt(insert)

sq(override query)-->exp-->upd-->tgt(update).

As part of performance tuning i need to implement above in single flow.Coming to override for update, we have an extra filter compared to insert override with NULL check of Key.

I have tried by making union of both the results, but its taking time. Please suggest me the alternative way to achieve above req in single flow.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make sure the SQ gets all data and put a condition in the Update Transformation, like IIF(ISNULL(Your_Key), DD_INSERT, DD_UPDATE). That's it.